# Installing another TTS language for Speech Services by Google on Moto G22 with Android 12 (OSMand navigation)

Tags: text-to-speech

I have a Moto g22 with Android 12 and am trying to get German language navigation in OSMand.  I have set the language for voice prompts to German in OSMand (for the relevant profile: Configure Profile → Navigation settings → Voice prompts -> Language → TTS/German).  English language navigation works fine using Google TTS, but when I set it to German I hear nothing.  When I go to Settings → System → Languages & input → Text-to-speech output, set the language to German, and tap "Play", I hear nothing.  If I set the language to English and then tap "Play", I hear a voice speaking in English.  The engine is set to "Speech services by Google".

As a workaround, I could download OsmAnds pre-recorded voices, but that's suboptimal as it doesn't include street names, so I would prefer to get Google Text-to-Speech to work for a German language output.

How can I get Speech Services by Google on the Moto G22 with Android 12 to speak German to me?  Do I need to download a language pack on an additional app in some way?

On my tablet (Lenovo Tab M10 with Android 10) German voice prompts work fine in OSMand as well as when I press "play" in the "Text-to-speech output" settings.

Comment: Please edit your post to confirm you tried changing the language within the OSMand app, https://osmand.net/docs/user/personal/global-settings/#display-language

Comment: @MorrisonChang Done, but it doesn't work in the system settings test either, so the problem is independent of OSMand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **download the voice data** first.

Setting the voice language to German is not enough to trigger Android to propose to install missing German voice data, nor to warn that such voice data is not currently installed.  Rather, it simply says nothing (literally).

From the "Text-to-speech output" settings, there is another settings menu accessed to the right of the "Preferred engine" entry.  Here, tap "Install voice data", then the relevant language.

After doing this, the voice prompts work in the settings test and in OSMand.